# Yii2: Application can't be executed. Apache shows "Index of"

Tags: php, postgresql, apache, yii2, bitnami

I developed a Yii2 application that works in my computer with Debian.

Then I installed [Bitnami WAPP](https://bitnami.com/stack/wapp) in a computer with Windows 8 and I tried to execute it but it doesn't work. It shows the content like a folder instead of execute the code:

[image: Index of instead of executing]

I thought that Apache was having a problem and it can't execute PHP, so I tried to execute a basic example and it works perfect:

```
<?php 
  phpinfo(); 
?>
```

[image: Basic PHP example executed successfully]

**UPDATE:** I think the problem was a wrong address. But now it shows this error:

[image: Error 500]
I hope all this information can help.

**Apache log:**

```
[Thu Jul 12 08:22:35.576377 2018] [php7:warn] [pid 5100:tid 1004] [client ::1:56103] PHP Warning:  require(C:\\Bitnami\\wappstack-7.1.19-0\\apache2\\htdocs\\donaciones-yii\\backend\\web/../../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\\Bitnami\\wappstack-7.1.19-0\\apache2\\htdocs\\donaciones-yii\\backend\\web\\index.php on line 5
[Thu Jul 12 08:22:35.576377 2018] [php7:error] [pid 5100:tid 1004] [client ::1:56103] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'C:\\Bitnami\\wappstack-7.1.19-0\\apache2\\htdocs\\donaciones-yii\\backend\\web/../../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.;C:/Bitnami/wappstack-7.1.19-0/php/PEAR') in C:\\Bitnami\\wappstack-7.1.19-0\\apache2\\htdocs\\donaciones-yii\\backend\\web\\index.php on line 5
```

**Apache access.log:**

```
::1 - - [12/Jul/2018:08:22:35 -0300] "GET /donaciones-yii/backend/web/ HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

**donaciones-yii/backend/web/index.php:**

```
<?php
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', false);
defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');

require(__DIR__ . '/../../vendor/autoload.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/../../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/bootstrap.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/../config/bootstrap.php');

$config = yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::merge(
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/main.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/main-local.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/../config/main.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/../config/main-local.php')
);

(new yii\web\Application($config))->run();
```

Comment: check your error log, 500 is a general error. Or (if you can) enable debug mode: ini_set("display_errors", true); or in php.ini

Comment: Your script require `vendor` directory in your root (`donaciones-yii`), but there is no that.

Comment: You should run composer setup, as far as I understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are opening a folder on your WAPP that is not meant to be opened in browser.

Your public application for the browser is most probably located in:

http://localhost/frontend/web/

and:
http://localhost/backend/web/

These are the folders that you should be checking and that should work.

Opening just http://localhost/ is not meant for serving publicly and what you see is expected behavior.

in a production scenario you would need to set your DocumentRoot to eg "/var/www/frontend/web" so you would have only the relevant folder served to public

Answer (score 1):

You got a "Index of" page, because you have no any index page, which can be auto loaded in each directory.

Try to load a requirements.php page by using your browser, in your case,  http://localhost/donaciones-yii/requirements.php

Have you tried to run yii.bat? It must generate all required pages like index.php and others.

If nothing helps, you can see official wiki pages like next:

https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/171/to-configure-yii-path-in-windows-platform
https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/534/a-very-easy-way-to-setup-yiic-on-wamp-server-without-extra-windows-settings